# Unity WaitForSeconds(3) waits for approximately 1 second on Android when ApplicationFocus changes

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am seeing some very strange behaviour with WaitForSeconds function in a coroutine while running on Android.

If I run the following TestCoroutine on Unity Editor everything works fine but when running on Android I see that the WaitForSeconds(3) waits for only approximately 1-2 seconds.

```
private IEnumerator TestCoroutine() {
     Debug.Log("!@! 0 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: " + Time.timeScale);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
     Debug.Log("!@! 1 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: " + Time.timeScale);
     yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3);
     Debug.Log("!@! 2 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: " + Time.timeScale);
 }
```

This returns (in logcat):

```
 2019-08-26 16:19:52.676 14700-14793/? I/Unity: !@! 0 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: 1
 2019-08-26 16:19:54.408 14700-14793/? I/Unity: !@! 1 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: 1
 2019-08-26 16:19:57.426 14700-14793/? I/Unity: !@! 2 TestCoroutine Time.timeScale: 1
```

As you can see the timestamp difference between the first call and the second is 1.732 even though we call WaitForSeconds(3). After doing WaitForSecondsRealtime(3) we can see the timestamp difference is 3.018 (0.018 is probably the time until the next frame was called).

Clarifications:

This only happens in Android.

The coroutine is being called with a simple StartCoroutine(TestCoroutine());

This happens around some ApplicationFocus stuff. Specifically: minimising the app and returning to the app.

There is a call to StopAllCoroutines in the code where this TestCoroutine is also being called but it makes no difference whether it is commented out or not.

Any help will be appreciated whether you've seen something similar or just have an idea!

Thanks!

([This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1660707/waitforseconds3-on-android-waits-less-than-expecte.html) is a link to the question in Unity answers).

Comment: Are you intiating this CoRoutine from Start() or Awake() by chance?

Comment: Nope. The app comes back into focus and from there this coroutine is called. There are of course other conditions but the core issue stays the same: I call WaitForSeconds(3) and get a 1-2 second wait...

Comment: Where and when are you triggering the coroutine? It is important call the routine properly because as the unity documentation says: '_There are some factors which can mean the actual amount of time waited does not precisely match the amount of time specified_' [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Comment: The coroutine is started when the app returns to focus. On the Unity answers thread I tested some different approaches to this issue and with one of those approaches I saw that the Time.deltaTime was still being added to when the app was out of focus. This was really weird since it did show that the deltaTime was adding up correctly for 1-2 frames then suddenly the unfocused time got added on to that.